# Weird behavior with the $@ variable

Tags: shell, unix, variables

As I understand and read it, `$@` turns into "arg1" "arg2" "arg3".
But it seems to have some weird behavior in some cases when quoted.

**Test 1, $@**

```
$ function somefunc { sh -c "echo $@"; }
$ somefunc 1 2 3
> + somefunc 1 2 3
> + sh -c 'echo 1' 2 3
> 1
```

The expected output is 1 2 3, the output I get is 1. Now I see that, for some reason, it seems to only pass `echo 1` as command, but why does `"echo "1" "2" "3""` turn into it? I would maybe have expected `echo`  because the " before echo may get closed by the " before 1.
 
**Test 2, $***

```
$ function somefunc { sh -c "echo $*"; }
$ somefunc 1 2 3
> + somefunc 1 2 3
> + sh -c 'echo 1 2 3'
> 1 2 3
```

This is pretty obvious and works, just to make sure. After all `$*` passes `1 2 3`, not `"1" "2" "3"`.
 
**Test 3, $@ and $***

```
$ function somefunc { sh -c "echo $@ $*"; }
$ somefunc 1 2 3
> + somefunc 1 2 3
> + sh -c 'echo 1 2 3 1 2 3'
> 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

This seems to work again weirdly enough. But I don't get how `"echo "1" "2" "3" 1 2 3"` turns into `'echo 1 2 3 1 2 3'` and doesn't follow the "pattern" that only `"echo $@"`did.

**Test 4, $@ and a string**

```
$ function somefunc { sh -c "echo $@ hi"; }
$ somefunc 1 2 3
> + somefunc 1 2 3
> + sh -c 'echo 1' 2 '3 hi'
> 1
```

This again follows the pattern of `"echo $@"`, even thought, as I see it, it is pretty much the same as `"echo $@ $*"` since `$*` turns into a string after all.
What also puzzles me is that it turned into `'echo 1' 2 '3 hi'`, the first test would have suggested `'echo 1' 2 3 hi` (without the two `'` surrounding `3 hi`)

**Test 5, $@ and $var**

```
$ var="hi"
> + var=hi
$ function somefunc { sh -c "echo $@ $var"; }
$ somefunc 1 2 3
> + somefunc 1 2 3
> + sh -c 'echo 1 2 3 hi'
> 1 2 3 hi
```

This works again. So `$@` seems to work if another variable follows it.

The tests are also possible with `su user -c` or `bash -c` instead of `sh -c`, so I suppose also every other command that executes the next given argument.

I now seem to have gotten some kind of behavior out of it,
but I do still not understand this behavior.
What am I missing here?

Comment: For Test 1 and Test 4, the key bit you may be missing from `man bash` description of `$@` is *If the double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the
expansion of the first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original word, and the expansion of the last parameter
is  joined  with  the  last  part  of the original word.*

Comment: @BrianSwift: Thanks, I have indeed missed that! This makes much more sense now.

Comment: Test 3 is interesting.  IMO, it is another instance of bash violating the sh spec (and its own man page).  `ash`, `dash`, `zsh`, and `ksh` all output just `1`.  Of those I tested, `bash` is the only shell to output `1 2 3 1 2 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [sh language spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) has this to say about `$@`:

**Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double-quotes, and where field splitting (see Field Splitting ) is performed, each positional parameter shall expand as a separate field, with the provision that the expansion of the first parameter shall still be joined with the beginning part of the original word (assuming that the expanded parameter was embedded within a word), and the expansion of the last parameter shall still be joined with the last part of the original word. If there are no positional parameters, the expansion of '@' shall generate zero fields, even when '@' is double-quoted.**

This means that the string  `"echo $@ $*"` where the positional parameters are `1`, `2`, `3` should expand to `"echo 1" "2" "3 1 2 3"`, so that your test 3 should output the string `1`.  The fact that bash incorrectly expands the string to `"echo 1 2 3 1 2 3"` and outputs `1 2 3 1 2 3` is indicative of a bug in bash.

The usual technique for dealing with this (yet another) oddity of sh grammar rules is to only use $@ in double quotes when it is a distinct word.  In other words, it's okay to write `"$@"`, but don't put `$@` in double quotes unless it is the only thing inside the double quotes.

Comment: +1 Interesting. But this still doesn't specify what "$@ $@" would make ;-). can anybody see how this is documented?

Answer (score 1):

Using @BrianSwift's hint, everything makes perfectly sense, except for **Test3** (here, it is **not** the case that we get three arguments with the first having a prefix of `'echo '` and the third having a suffix of `' $*'`. Instead, the result is a single argument).

But that may probably be explained with the fact that both `$@` and `$*` are "special" variables for which special code in the shell exists. I assume the existence of `$*` just overrides the special behaviour noticed by @BrianSwift, because `$*` is evaluated later.

Try swapping the order: `somefunc() { sh -x "echo $* $@"; }`. You will get the split-with-prefix-and-suffix behaviour again which seems to support my above assumption.

So to conclude, everything can be explained with a reference to the manual except for Test3 whose behaviour is probably a bit "underdocumented".

Comment: Isn't Test5 quite the same as Test3? I guess $@ has the special behavior that it "unifies" if another variable is given anywhere after it in the quotation, but not if another variable is given before it. This seems a bit weird, but with some more tests it seems to match. `$var=hi; somefunc { sh -c "echo $@ $var"; }` returns `1 2 3 hi`, `somefunc { sh -c "echo $@ hi $var"; }` returns `1 2 3 hi hi`, etc. Those special cases could be documented better in my opinion. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Test 3 is not underdocumented.  It is a bug in bash, as the correct output should be just `1`, which is the behavior exhibited by zsh, ash, dash, and ksh.

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand and read it, $@ turns into "arg1" "arg2" "arg3".

No, `"$@"` turns into `"arg1" "arg2" "arg3"`. The quotes matter.

Comment: I still don't understand the behavior of the tests I did. Could you explain that to me? What exactly happens there?